# find words that can be made from a string in python

Tags: python, linux, dictionary

im fairly new to python and im not sure how to tackle my problem
im trying to make a program that can take a string of 15 characters from a .txt file and find words that you can make from those characters with a dictionary file, than output those words to another text file.
this is what i have tried:
attempting to find words that don't contain the characters and removing them from the list
various anagram solver type programs of git hub

i tried this `sudo pip3 install anagram-solver`but it has been 3 hours on 15 characters and it is still running

im new so please tell me if im forgetting something

Comment: Could you provide the actual code and maybe a look into the different files you used?

Comment: i don't have a list of all of the things i have tried but they all were broken except the one off pypi.org which wont give an answer https://medium.com/python-anagram-solver/python-anagram-solver-edb2646b65f8 https://pypi.org/project/anagram-solver/ i scrapped the code i madde because it was seriously bad https://github.com/parekhparth/AnagramSolver this one i couldn't compile for some reason https://github.com/patrickleweryharris/anagram-solver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for "perfect" anagrams, i.e. those that contain exactly the same number of characters, not a subset, it's pretty easy:

- take your word-to-find, sort it by its letters
- take your dictionary, sort each word by its letters
- if the sorted versions match, they're anagrams

```
def find_anagrams(seek_word):
    sorted_seek_word = sorted(seek_word.lower())
    for word in open("/usr/share/dict/words"):
        word = word.strip()  # remove trailing newline
        sorted_word = sorted(word.lower())
        if sorted_word == sorted_seek_word and word != seek_word:
            print(seek_word, word)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_anagrams("begin")
    find_anagrams("nicer")
    find_anagrams("decor")
```

prints (on my macOS machine – Windows machines won't have `/usr/share/dict/words` by default, and some Linux distributions need it installed separately)

```
begin being
begin binge
nicer cerin
nicer crine
decor coder
decor cored
decor Credo
```

## EDIT

A second variation that finds all words that are assemblable from the letters in the original word, using `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections


def find_all_anagrams(seek_word):
    seek_word_counter = collections.Counter(seek_word.lower())
    for word in open("/usr/share/dict/words"):
        word = word.strip()  # remove trailing newline
        word_counter = collections.Counter(word.strip())
        if word != seek_word and all(
            n <= seek_word_counter[l] for l, n in word_counter.items()
        ):
            yield word


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("decoration", set(find_all_anagrams("decoration")))
```

Outputs e.g.

```
decoration {'carte', 'drona', 'roit', 'oat', 'cantred', 'rond', 'rid', 'centroid', 'trine', 't', 'tenai', 'cond', 'toroid', 'recon', 'contra', 'dain', 'cootie', 'iao', 'arctoid', 'oner', 'indart', 'tine', 'nace', 'rident', 'cerotin', 'cran', 'eta', 'eoan', 'cardoon', 'tone', 'trend', 'trinode', 'coaid', 'ranid', 'rein', 'end', 'actine', 'ide', 'cero', 'iodate', 'corn', 'oer', 'retia', 'nidor', 'diter', 'drat', 'tec', 'tic', 'creat', 'arent', 'coon', 'doater', 'ornoite', 'terna', 'docent', 'tined', 'edit', 'octroi', 'eric', 'read', 'toned', 'c', 'tera', 'can', 'rocta', 'cortina', 'adonite', 'iced', 'no', 'natr', 'net', 'oe', 'rodeo', 'actor', 'otarine', 'on', 'cretin', 'ericad', 'dance', 'tornade', 'tinea', 'coontie', 'anerotic', 'acrite', 'ra', 'danio', 'inroad', 'inde', 'tied', 'tar', 'coronae', 'tid', 'rad', 'doc', 'derat', 'tea', 'acerin', 'ronde', 'recti', 'areito', 'drain', 'odontic', 'octoad', 'rio', 'actin', 'tread', 'rect', 'ariot', 'road', 'doctrine', 'enactor', 'indoor', 'toco', 'ton', 'trice', 'norite', 'nea', 'coda', 'noria', 'rot', 'trona', 'rice', 'arite', 'eria', 'orad', 'rate', 'toed', 'enact', 'crinet', 'cento', 'arid', 'coot', 'nat', 'nar', 'cain', 'at', 'antired', 'ear', 'triode', 'doter', 'cedarn', 'orna', 'rand', 'tari', 'crea', 'tiar', 'retan', 'tire', 'cora', 'aroid', 'iron', 'tenio', 'enroot', 'd', 'oaric', 'acetin', 'tain', 'neat', 'noter', 'tien', 'aortic', 'tode', 'dicer', 'irate', 'tie', 'canid', 'ado', 'noticer', 'arn', 'nacre', 'ceration', 'ratine', 'denaro', 'cotoin', 'aint', 'canto', 'cinter', 'decani', 'roon', 'donor', 'acnode', 'aide', 'doer', 'tacnode', 'oread', 'acetoin', 'rine', 'acton', 'conoid', 'a', 'otocrane', 'norate', 'care', 'ticer', 'io', 'detain', 'cedar', 'ta', 'toadier', 'atone', 'cornet', 'dacoit', 'toric', 'orate', 'arni', 'adroit', 'rend', 'tanier', 'rooted', 'doit', 'dier', 'odorate', 'trica', 'rated', 'cotonier', 'dine', 'roid', 'cairned', 'cat', 'i', 'coin', 'octine', 'trod', 'orc', 'cardo', 'eniac', 'arenoid', 'erd', 'creant', 'oda', 'ratio', 'ceria', 'ad', 'acorn', 'dorn', 'deric', 'credit', 'door', 'cinder', 'cantor', 'er', 'doon', 'coner', 'donate', 'roe', 'tora', 'antic', 'racoon', 'ooid', 'noa', 'tae', 'coroa', 'earn', 'retain', 'canted', 'norie', 'rota', 'tao', 'redan', 'rondo', 'entia', 'ctenoid', 'cent', 'daroo', 'inrooted', 'roed', 'adore', 'coat', 'e', 'rat', 'deair', 'arend', 'coir', 'acid', 'coronate', 'rodent', 'acider', 'iota', 'codo', 'redaction', 'cot', 'aeric', 'tonic', 'candier', 'decart', 'dicta', 'dot', 'recoat', 'caroon', 'rone', 'tarie', 'tarin', 'teca', 'oar', 'ocrea', 'ante', 'creation', 'tore', 'conto', 'tairn', 'roc', 'conter', 'coeditor', 'certain', 'roncet', 'decator', 'not', 'coatie', 'toran', 'caid', 'redia', 'root', 'cad', 'cartoon', 'n', 'coed', 'cand', 'neo', 'coronadite', 'dare', 'dartoic', 'acoin', 'detar', 'dite', 'trade', 'train', 'ordinate', 'racon', 'citron', 'dan', 'doat', 'nito', 'tercia', 'rote', 'cooer', 'acone', 'rita', 'caret', 'dern', 'enatic', 'too', 'cried', 'tade', 'dit', 'orient', 'ria', 'torn', 'coati', 'cnida', 'note', 'tried', 'acrid', 'nitro', 'acron', 'tern', 'one', 'it', 'naio', 'dor', 'ea', 'ca', 'ire', 'inert', 'orcanet', 'cine', 'coe', 'nardoo', 'deota', 'den', 'toi', 'adion', 'to', 'rite', 'nectar', 'rane', 'riant', 'cod', 'de', 'adit', 'airt', 'ie', 'retin', 'toon', 'cane', 'aeon', 'are', 'cointer', 'actioner', 'crin', 'detrain', 'art', 'cant', 'ort', 'tored', 'antoeci', 'tier', 'cite', 'onto', 'coater', 'tranced', 'atonic', 'roi', 'in', 'roan', 'decoat', 'rain', 'cronet', 'ronco', 'dont', 'citer', 'redact', 'cider', 'nor', 'octan', 'ration', 'doina', 'rie', 'aero', 'noted', 'crate', 'crain', 'cadet', 'condite', 'ran', 'odeon', 'date', 'eat', 'intoed', 'cation', 'carone', 'ratoon', 'retina', 'tiao', 'nice', 'nodi', 'codon', 'coo', 'torc', 'dent', 'entad', 'ne', 'toe', 'dae', 'decant', 'redcoat', 'coiner', 'irade', 'air', 'oint', 'coronet', 'radon', 'ce', 'octonare', 'oaten', 'citrean', 'dice', 'dancer', 'carotid', 'cretion', 'don', 'cion', 'nei', 'tead', 'nori', 'nacrite', 'ootid', 'rancid', 'dornic', 'orenda', 'cairn', 'aroon', 'coardent', 'aider', 'notice', 'cored', 'adorn', 'tad', 'carid', 'otic', 'dian', 'od', 'dint', 'tercio', 'die', 'conred', 'tice', 'rant', 'candor', 'anti', 'dar', 'antre', 'cornea', 'ordain', 'corona', 'recta', 'redo', 'tare', 'coranto', 'action', 'caird', 'creta', 'naid', 'tri', 'acre', 'crane', 'coated', 'citronade', 'anoetic', 'tenor', 'anode', 'triad', 'ceratoid', 'rod', 'idea', 'carton', 'cortin', 'endaortic', 'dicot', 'tend', 'da', 'tod', 'erotica', 'cord', 'coreid', 'toader', 'dace', 'tan', 'editor', 'rection', 'toner', 'cone', 'ni', 'tide', 'coder', 'din', 'ocote', 'ore', 'daer', 'octane', 'darn', 'do', 'reit', 'na', 'catenoid', 'tron', 'condor', 'crinated', 'cordon', 'crone', 'toad', 'noir', 'into', 'tirade', 'nadir', 'ant', 'ade', 'droit', 'icon', 'drone', 'ared', 'cardin', 'nid', 'dire', 'orcin', 'donator', 'rani', 'tane', 'ace', 'iodo', 'doria', 'ride', 'eon', 'ornate', 'cedrat', 'aire', 'carotin', 'dation', 'tear', 'onca', 'cote', 'taroc', 'con', 'nod', 'dinero', 'ecad', 'recant', 'ae', 'octad', 'cor', 'doctor', 'acridone', 'neti', 'cordite', 'crotin', 'aneroid', 'diota', 'coorie', 'dita', 'aconite', 'nard', 'cadent', 'ectad', 'rance', 'rea', 'tai', 'denat', 'rood', 'acne', 'decan', 'ani', 'rit', 'cit', 'cetin', 'odor', 'acorned', 'iceroot', 'inro', 'crood', 'daric', 'dacite', 'trone', 'acier', 'reina', 'oncia', 'drant', 'acrodont', 'nacred', 'cotrine', 'dinar', 'tean', 'atoner', 'toorie', 'nadorite', 'cardon', 'taen', 'tin', 'conte', 'acoine', 'dater', 'diact', 'aid', 'anodic', 'coronated', 'direct', 're', 'era', 'anticor', 'triace', 'octoid', 'dao', 'corta', 'edict', 'trode', 'ode', 'orant', 'niter', 'centrad', 'cater', 'tronc', 'coronad', 'r', 'toro', 'ar', 'once', 'ora', 'trace', 'creodont', 'erotic', 'ai', 'troca', 'ion', 'tecon', 'tra', 'acor', 'radio', 'acred', 'croon', 'tricae', 'recto', 'riden', 'andorite', 'taro', 'red', 'dear', 'ate', 'tinder', 'trin', 'deacon', 'ardent', 'aer', 'arc', 'crine', 'dart', 'diet', 'riot', 'tanrec', 'tor', 'noetic', 'ret', 'trance', 'ona', 'rind', 'coto', 'daoine', 'teind', 'toa', 'inter', 'code', 'cart', 'aion', 'detin', 'core', 'oont', 'rent', 'cedrin', 'card', 'trained', 'o', 'recoin', 'cro', 'and', 'diner', 'id', 'cordant', 'cedron', 'ditone', 'odic', 'cadi', 'cerin', 'nit', 'ecoid', 'nide', 'ean', 'andric', 'tind', 'raid', 'crena', 'oroide', 'roadite', 'canter', 'idant', 'cade', 'race', 'ten', 'caner', 'tarn', 'cooter', 'etna', 'tornadic', 'irone', 'ice', 'en', 'oord', 'oared', 'draine', 'cordate', 'react', 'reaction', 'tornado', 'troco', 'niota', 'carotenoid', 'an', 'cader', 'naric', 'car', 'centiar', 'ti', 'cearin', 'aroint', 'crined', 'iter', 'di', 'or', 'trio', 'dari', 'oration', 'orcein', 'coned', 'odorant', 'dean', 'coadore', 'cate', 'drate', 'dirten', 'ted', 'done', 'cadre', 'ocean', 'tired', 'adet', 'dirt', 'te', 'nae', 'ceti', 'cern', 'rotan', 'doe', 'roto', 'dote', 'node', 'ait', 'act', 'canoe', 'rode'}
```

Comment: thanks this is helpful but ideally i would like to be able to find shorter words is there a way to implement this to output shorter words? thanks

Comment: @TheBigBear390 Added one.

Comment: in the end i put all letters that i didnt want to make the list from and used this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-remove-words-containing-list-characters/